# Custom UITableviewCell IBOutlet always nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I have a custom UITableViewCell subclass with a simple IBOutlet setup for a UILabel.

```
class SegmentCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var test: UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        test.text = "Some Text"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Convinced I have everything set up correct have followed other answers, but the UILabel is always nil.

ViewController:
viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(SegmentCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

cellForForAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! SegmentCell
    return cell
}
```

- Cell is set to Custom
- Reuse identifier is correct
- Cells class is SegmentCell
- Tableview content is Dynamic Prototypes

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't need call self.tableView.registerClass(SegmentCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell") on viewDidLoad, just set the prototypeCells class to "SegmentCell" on Mainstoryboard.

Comment: I realise this is a really old question, but it currently has no answer and I happened upon it because I'm encountering a similar problem. In your case, I think the `weak var` is the key - if your `SegmentCell` is the only thing that ever holds a reference to the `UILabel`, that won't contribute to the retain count and so the label will be deallocated because nobody has a strong reference to it. By the time you attempt to set `.text`, it's already gone.

Answer (score 11):

Since You are uisg Xib file you have to register with ,

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "yourNib", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellFromNib")
```

Think, if only register with class ,system will not know the its Xib.This work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the way you register your cell, it is not going to be loading it from a storyboard or xib file.  It will be invoking that init method only.  Your init method does not create the label, so it will always be `nil`.

You should also use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:forIndexPath:)` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:)`. The latter predates storyboards and will return `nil` unless you have previously created a cell with that identifier and returned it.

Lastly, the init method that the `tableView` is calling is not the one you've implemented, or the app would crash on `test.text = ...` while trying to unwrap a `nil` optional.

Comment: Im creating it in the storyboard, in the prototype cell.

Comment: Then you should not register it with the `tableView` in code, and you can expect `init(coder:)` to get called.

Comment: So I've removed the `tableView.registerClass` and changed the init method in the SegmentCell class to `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {` still having the same issue

Comment: You should also use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:forIndexPath:)` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:)`.  The latter predates storyboards and will return `nil` unless you have previously created a cell with that identifier and returned it.

Comment: Just to be clear, what should my init method look like, because I've not tried several

Comment: You do not need one.  You can set that text in the storyboard.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to change the label in my custom class...thus why I have an outlet set up to it

Comment: Sure, but you probably don't want to do that in init.  I would expect you to do that right after you dequeue it in your view controller.  The init method will only get called once, and you may reuse that cell many times.

Comment: Ahhh, so call a method in the class to update stuff after I dequeue it, I seeeeee!

Comment: Yeah, given the way you have your label IBOutlet setup, you can move that test.text line from your init method directly after you dequeue the cell and before you return it.  It should work.

Comment: Yeah, I subclassed the label because to VC was getting a bit fat, so I wanted to move the functionality into it's own class, but of course the cell only gets initialised once then dequeued...maybe I should sleep THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewCell class and ContentView class can't be same.

Answer (score 0):

You should register it first in the viewDidLoad function.

```
self.tableView.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Comment: This is actually on the right track. But the call is this: TableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "CellXibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, after add custom cell class to cell in tableview placed in Storyboard.
I also register cell, like in documentation. But now I solve my issue.

"I remove registering and inspect cell again, all IBOutlets initialised"

Answer (score 0):

I think that basically the outlets are not setup yet at init time.  If you want to get to the outlets and manipulate them, then override didMoveToSuperview or similar and do it in there.  For instance, this is what I had to do to get to the button outlet in my cell:

```
open class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // Top stack view, not the inner one.
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonView: UIButton?

    open override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        buttonView?.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    }

    func adjustForAccessibilityCategory(accessible: Bool) {
        if accessible {
            stackView.axis = .vertical
            stackView.alignment = .leading
            stackView.spacing = 2
        } else {
            stackView.axis = .horizontal
            stackView.alignment = .center
            stackView.spacing = 20
        }
    }

    open override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            adjustForAccessibilityCategory(accessible: traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory.isAccessibilityCategory)
        }
    }
}
```